# Quicksort Without Recursion

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

Am teaching myself about sorting techniques and trying my hand at a [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) implementation. I found a lot of examples based on recursion but didn't want to go that route in a language that doesn't support tail-call optimization.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void InsertionSort<T>(this IList<T> values, int startIndex, int endIndex, IComparer<T> comparer) {
        var left = startIndex;
        var right = 0;
        var temp = default(T);

        while (left < endIndex) {
            right = left;
            temp = values[++left];

            while ((right >= startIndex) && (0 < comparer.Compare(values[right], temp))) {
                values[(right + 1)] = values[right--];
            }

            values[(right + 1)] = temp;
        }
    }
    public static void InsertionSort<T>(this IList<T> values, IComparer<T> comparer) {
        InsertionSort(values, 0, (values.Count - 1), comparer);
    }
    public static void InsertionSort<T>(this IList<T> values) {
        InsertionSort(values, Comparer<T>.Default);
    }
    public static void QuickSort<T>(this IList<T> values, int startIndex, int endIndex, IComparer<T> comparer, IRandomNumberGenerator randomNumberGenerator) {
        var range = (startIndex, endIndex);
        var stack = new Stack<(int, int)>();

        do {
            startIndex = range.startIndex;
            endIndex = range.endIndex;

            if ((endIndex - startIndex + 1) < 31) {
                values.InsertionSort(startIndex, endIndex, comparer);

                continue;
            }

            var pivot = values.SampleMedian(startIndex, endIndex, comparer, randomNumberGenerator);
            var left = startIndex;
            var right = endIndex;

            while (left <= right) {
                while (0 > comparer.Compare(values[left], pivot)) { left++; }
                while (0 > comparer.Compare(pivot, values[right])) { right--; }

                if (left <= right) {
                    values.Swap(left++, right--);
                }
            }

            if (startIndex < right) {
                stack.Push((startIndex, right));
            }

            if (left < endIndex) {
                stack.Push((left, endIndex));
            }
        }
        while (stack.TryPop(out range));
    }
    public static void QuickSort<T>(this IList<T> values, IComparer<T> comparer, IRandomNumberGenerator randomNumberGenerator) {
        QuickSort(values, 0, (values.Count - 1), comparer, randomNumberGenerator);
    }
    public static void QuickSort<T>(this IList<T> values) {
        QuickSort(values, Comparer<T>.Default, FastRandom.Default);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private static T SampleMedian<T>(this IList<T> values, int startIndex, int endIndex, IComparer<T> comparer, IRandomNumberGenerator randomNumberGenerator) {
        var left = randomNumberGenerator.NextInt32(startIndex, endIndex);
        var middle = randomNumberGenerator.NextInt32(startIndex, endIndex);
        var right = randomNumberGenerator.NextInt32(startIndex, endIndex);

        if (0 > comparer.Compare(values[right], values[left])) {
            Swap(values, right, left);
        }

        if (0 > comparer.Compare(values[middle], values[left])) {
            Swap(values, middle, left);
        }

        if (0 > comparer.Compare(values[right], values[middle])) {
            Swap(values, right, middle);
        }

        return values[middle];
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private static void Swap<T>(this IList<T> values, int xIndex, int yIndex) {
        var temp = values[xIndex];

        values[xIndex] = values[yIndex];
        values[yIndex] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What IDE are you using? The code formatting is very non-C#-ish. It looks more like JavaScript ;-]

Comment: I also noticed that you are using `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` extensively in your code. Why? Is this really so performance-critical? Have you benchmarked it?

Comment: It's a pitty that you don't try to incorporate the suggestions from earlier reviews. The code is virtually as _bad_ or _weird_ as before :-| If you like a certain style then you have to say it because otherwise it's pointless to write anything.

Comment: @t3chb0t I use Visual Studio with modified, but uniform, settings for formatting in all languages. The deviation from idiomatic C# styling is because I use *at least* three different languages in any given day and grew weary of remembering all the different "rules". As for other stylistic concerns: I have stated on many many questions and comments now that I generally only care about correctness and performance (in that order). When working solo, the only truly important rule when it comes to style is to be consistent; which I try really hard to do.

Comment: @t3chb0t Whether `SampleMedian<T>` is performance critical or not is debatable but `Swap<T>` definitely is; the method likely gets inlined by the JIT compiler with or without it (because the method is "small" and doesn't violate any restrictions) but I chose to tag the method anyways "just in case". Whether this is good practice or not is something I'm still personally on the fence about but empirical testing has showed that this pattern doesn't appear to ever do harm.

Comment: "_I generally only care about correctness and performance_" - the compiler and unit tests will grant you the former and the profiler the later. What exactly do you expect from a code review?

Comment: @I'lladdcommentstomorrow Those techniques only go so far; unit tests aren't going to handle cases I haven't covered (and might suffer from their own bugs) while profiling can only tell me where hot spots are, not necessarily what to do about them. I know from extensive testing exactly where my performance bottlenecks are right now but have done all I can to try improve things; figured it was time to consult the public to see if they had any clever ideas or noticed me doing something stupid.

Answer (score 1):

All in all there is not much to comment. I like the iterative mechanism with the stack. Trying other collections (linked list, dictionary, hashset etc.) doesn't seem to improve the performance.

One could argue that it would be nice to have the partition part in a dedicated function to improve readability, but again the algorithm isn't that hard to understand.

The really improvement of performance comes from the use of `InsertionSort()` when the range is smaller than 31 - and that magic number seems to be the right limit. And Insertion Sort seems to be the right choice over other simple algorithms like Selection Sort.

The performance gain from `SampleMedian()` is little or absent for smaller data sets, but is significant for larger (> 10000) - compared to let it return `values[startIndex]` or `values[startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2]`.

All in all a well designed algorithm optimized in respect to performance.

---

A minor thing in `SampleMedian()`:

I don't like:

```
if (0 > comparer.Compare(values[right], values[left]))
```

but rather:

```
if (comparer.Compare(values[right], values[left]) < 0)
```

but that's a matter of habit.

---

Of course you should check if the arguments are valid (`values != null`, `startIndex < endIndex` etc.)